# How does Deobfuscation with GWT-Log works in Production with Style Obfuscated?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, logging

I am using GWT 2.6 and GWT-log 3.3.0.
I tried to get remote log messages with [gwt-log](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/). I tried this:

```
Log.fatal("This is what an exception might look like", new RuntimeException("2 + 2 = 5"));
```

Here is my gwt.xml:

```
    <module rename-to='testgwt'>

<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />  


<inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-DEBUG" />
<inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-RemoteLogger" />

<set-property name="log_ConsoleLogger" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="log_DivLogger" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="log_FirebugLogger" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="log_GWTLogger" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="log_SystemLogger" value="ENABLED" />

<set-property name="compiler.emulatedStack" value="true" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>
```

My entry point class:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    Log.setUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
          @Override
          public void execute() {
            onModuleLoad2();
          }
        });

}

public void onModuleLoad2() {

   Log.fatal("This is what an exception might look like", new RuntimeException("2 + 2 = 5"));
}
```

I can see that in WEB-INF/deploy/web/symbolMaps/ there are many files of size 4.3MB each. So I guess the symbolMaps are generated successful.

My remote servlet config is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gwt-log-remote-logger-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.RemoteLoggerServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>symbolMaps</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/deploy/testgwt/symbolMaps/</param-value>
    </init-param>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gwt-log-remote-logger-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testgwt/gwt-log</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I compile with style obfuscated. In my WEB-INF/lib folder I have the gwt-log.3.3.jar file.

On the client side I get

```
(-:-) 2014-02-20 23:09:54,529 [FATAL] This is what an exception might look like
java.lang.RuntimeException: 2 + 2 = 5
    at Unknown.ui(StackTraceCreator.java:180)
    at Unknown.Zf(StackTraceCreator.java:518)
    at Unknown.Yf(Throwable.java:56)
    at Unknown.kh(Exception.java:29)
    at Unknown.mh(RuntimeException.java:29)
    at Unknown.PW(Testgwt.java:66)
    at Unknown.TW(Testgwt.java:52)
    at Unknown.ki(SchedulerImpl.java:180)
    at Unknown.bi(SchedulerImpl.java:345)
    at Unknown.oi(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at Unknown.ii(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
    at Unknown.Kh(Impl.java:290)
    at Unknown.Oh(Impl.java:347)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:93)
    at Unknown.anonymous(UnloadSupport.java:42)
```

On the server side I get:

```
SEVERE: This is what an exception might look like
java.lang.RuntimeException: 2 + 2 = 5
    at Unknown.ui(StackTraceCreator.java:180)
    at Unknown.Zf(StackTraceCreator.java:518)
    at Unknown.Yf(Throwable.java:56)
    at Unknown.kh(Exception.java:29)
    at Unknown.mh(RuntimeException.java:29)
    at Unknown.PW(Testgwt.java:66)
    at Unknown.TW(Testgwt.java:52)
    at Unknown.ki(SchedulerImpl.java:180)
    at Unknown.bi(SchedulerImpl.java:345)
    at Unknown.oi(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at Unknown.ii(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
    at Unknown.Kh(Impl.java:290)
    at Unknown.Oh(Impl.java:347)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:93)
    at Unknown.anonymous(UnloadSupport.java:42)
```

**What do I have to do to get the deobfuscation on server side working in production with style obfuscated?**

Edit:

Even if I don't use:

symbolMaps
        WEB-INF/deploy/testgwt/symbolMaps/

It does not change anything. The path to the symbolMaps folder seems to be correct. There are also files in it which have been generated after gwt comile in my eclipse web application project. See this demo eclipse gwt project I made: https://github.com/confile/gwtlogtest

Edit: I run my app on a  Tomcat 7.0.52 server. In my catalina.log ther is the following warning:

```
Feb 21, 2014 12:08:11 AM com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.ServerLogImplJDK14 log
WARNING: Servlet configuration parameter 'symbolMaps' specifies directory
'WEB-INF/deploy/testgwt/symbolMaps/' which does not exist or is not relative 
 to your server's current working directory '/'

Feb 21, 2014 12:08:11 AM com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.ServerLogImplJDK14 log
WARNING: In order to enable stack trace deobfuscation, please specify 
the 'symbolMaps' <init-param> for the com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.RemoteLoggerServlet servlet in your web.xml
```

It seems that the symbolMaps cannot be found. I checked it is exactly at this path.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these properties in your module?

```
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true" />
```

Note that those properties should be removed if you want your production code being fully optimized.

Comment: I added this to my web.xml. Se my edit. I still don't get a stack trace deobfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Configuration and it works fine:
Client side Configuration (Task.gwt.xml):

```
<!-- Enabling server side logging: -->
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="SEVERE"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<!-- To show line number of occurred exception in server side logging (This will increase compiled js size): -->
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>

<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

Server side Configuration (web.xml):

```
<!-- gwt remote logging -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwt/ir.asta.zrm.cm.gwt.Task/remote_logging</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```